# MappingNotFoundException for *.hbm.xml when accessed by frontend plugin

Tags: hibernate, eclipse-rcp, osgi

I'm into a Eclipse RCP Application with Hibernate. I created a "service" plugin for the hibernate mappings - daos etc. For testing I created a "Main" Class/Method into this plugin. "Main" executes `HibernateUtil.initSessionFactory();` and does then some queries against the database regarding all mappings. It works fine.
When I execute the same method `HibernateUtil.initSessionFactory();` from another eclipse plugin e.g. "ui" I receive a:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
>   org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException:
>   resource:de/da/service/data/TblItem.hbm.xml not found

Exception when including the mappings:

> addResource("de/da/service/data/TblItem.hbm.xml")

---

Why is this happen, while the local call of the same method works fine?

```
public static void initSessionFactory() {

    try {
        SessionFactory sf = getSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        Session s = sf.getCurrentSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        if (ConnectionException.analyze(ex)) {
            throw new ConnectionException();
        }
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory current = null;
    if (config == null)
        config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();

    current = getSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return current ;
}

private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(SessionFactory sFactory) {

    if (sFactory == null) {
        try {

            config = new AnnotationConfiguration().
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect").
            setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread").
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db").
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "username").
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password").
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "0").
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true").
            setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true").
            setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true").
            setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "0").
            addResource("de/da/service/data/TblItem.hbm.xml").

            sFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    return sFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't respect the Buddy-Policy of the service plugin. I needed to add

> Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: 'name-of-plugin-with-hibernate-jars'

to the manifest of my service plugin. Hibernates Classloader will now find the xml mapping files.